# change background color of image button in custom notification when clicked

Tags: android, background-color, android-notifications

I have a custom notification layout that contains four image buttons.

I need to change the background color of the image buttons when user click on them.

I need to use

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recentAppButt);
imgButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

but this cause a nullpointerexception error because compiler can't find the recentAppButt image button because these image buttons are in the custom notification layout.

this is some code from the mainActivity.class in which i create or remove the notification

```
private void createNotificationIcons() {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("All Buttons!")
            .setOngoing(true) /** notification will appear as ongoing notification*/
            .build();                      
    /** set a custom layout to the notification in notification drawer  */
    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    notification.contentView = notificationView;

    Intent recentAppIntent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    recentAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Bundle recentAppBundle = new Bundle();   
    recentAppBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 1);
    recentAppIntent.putExtras(recentAppBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingrecentAppIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, recentAppIntent, 0);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.recentAppButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}


public class SwitchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle answerBundle = intent.getExtras();
        int userAnswer = answerBundle.getInt("userAnswer");
        if(userAnswer == 1) {
            ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recentAppButt);
            imgButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Recent Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Recent", "recent app butt clicked");
            openRecentApps();
        }
    }
}

public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    MainActivity.SwitchButtonListener switchButtonListener = mainActivity.new   SwitchButtonListener();

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        registerReceiver(switchButtonListener, new     IntentFilter(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
    return START_STICKY;
}

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(switchButtonListener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this the notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<!-- create home button in notification drawer -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/homeButt"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/discription"
    android:src="@drawable/home" />

<!-- create recent apps button in notification drawer -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/recentAppButt"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/discription"
    android:src="@drawable/recent" />

<!-- create lock screen button in notification drawer -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/lockScreenButt"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/discription"
    android:src="@drawable/lock" />

<!-- create allButtons button in notification drawer -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/allButtonsButt"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="#FF990000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/discription"
    android:src="@drawable/all_buttons" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The more important question: In which context do you call the mentioned code? You should use the view parameter that was passed in the onClick method to directly access the clicked view (ImageButton in your case). That means you would not need R.id.recentAppButt...

Comment: note that the image buttons are in the custom notification xml layout, I need to use the mentioned code in MainActivity.class that extends activity and that use activity-main.xml layout file.I use MainActivity to add or remove the notification and do some other things.

Comment: How about you tell us in more detail and with more code what you try to do? Because you talk about a notification but at the same time about an activity. Please make it more clear by adding more details and code.

Comment: My app have one activity that have a checkbox that create (when checked) or remove (when unchecked) the notification. I added some code, i wish to be useful.

Comment: your notification layout is missing.

Comment: The xml content of your R.layout.notification

Comment: yes, it can catch the content of the xml notification layout and this is the main problem, but what is the solution?!

Comment: Please copy and paste the layout content into this question....

Comment: i added the notification layout

Comment: According to the RemoteView documentation I am missing an apply() call to inflate the view. So I guess it can't find the button as it is not yet inflated. Never worked with a RemoteView but I would try that...

Comment: thanks for your effort

Comment: Did it work? If so, please share the solution

Comment: No, only i wanted to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in your layout file, your ImageView has parameters for height and width which are set to **wrap_parent**.

if any of those (layout_height or layout_width) are set to **wrap_content**, and you have don't have an actual image set on the ImageView, it's height is set to 0.
In other words, you should change the wrap_content to another value such as 100dp for example and see if the color changes.

Comment: It is a nice sol, but don't solve my problem.I need to use the setBackgroundColor function but i don't know how to get the image button object because they are in notification layout.

Comment: add your xml file where you define the ImageView itself as well - it is important to see what parameters you have added there.

Answer (score 0):

**findViewById** is a method of the **Activity** class and will not work on **RemoteViews** and notifications.
You are getting a null point exception because *R.id.recentAppButt* doesn't exist in your activity view.

You can achieve what you want by creating two icons with different background colours in your drawables folder. You can then switch between the two icons with the **setImageViewResource** method of the **RemoteViews** class as follows

```
notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.recentAppButt, R.drawable.icon_with_blue_background)
```

You then need to rebuild your notification and re-**notify** it through the **NotificationManager** so that the background colour is updated.